# Exchange Public Folders in Snow Leopard Mail.app

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail, public-folders

I am using Mail.app (running snow leopard) to connect to my email account on my school's Exchange 2007 server.  I get my Inbox just fine, and iCal connects to my Outlook Calendar just fine, but I cannot seem to get any of the Exchange Public Folders that I can automatically see when I am using Outlook on a Windows box.

The Account Type is shown as "Exchange 2007"

I did not have any luck Googling this problem, in fact most of the results I saw were dealing with the opposite problem:

[Remove MS Exchange Public Folders](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20051007051931489)

I am aware that my question is a duplicate of this:

https://superuser.com/questions/103115/apple-mail-app-all-exchange-folders-not-visible

but since that question did not get any responses, I am reposting.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can give you is to use Entourage. I wish the Public Folders were available through the OWA Lite version. I assume Microsoft's lack of support in this area is due to them phasing out Public Folders in later versions of Exchange.

Entourage is included in [MS Office 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/Office2008/shop-now.mspx).